# How to run an ASP .NET 6 API in a docker container on a raspberry pi / armv7

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

If I deploy my API directly I can start it via `dotnet <app.dll>`.
I want to deploy it in a container tho. However, the container always exits with an error code 132 or 130 depending on the Dockerfile used. I will post it here:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-bullseye-slim-arm32v7 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["API/API.csproj", "API/"]
RUN dotnet restore "API/API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API"
RUN dotnet build "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build -r linux-arm


FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish -r linux-arm

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API.dll"]
```

The first line of this Dockerfile is what I have been changing up in order to "find" the correct runtime. I tried many containers listed [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet) at the Linux arm32 Tags section. All containers I tried exit with an error immediately:
[image]

I would greatly appreciate any help on how to resolve this issue :)

EDIT:
I use a raspberry pi 4 Model B with 8GB of RAM

Comment: What stage does it fail on?

Comment: @DanielA.White how do I find out? `docker logs <container_id>` doesn't show me anything. After `docker run`, console also just enters new line (except the error 130, there I got told that app/libhostpolicy.so  is missing)

Comment: You are mixing 3.1 and 6.0

Comment: I also tried the 6.0 versions (in the beginning)

Comment: yes but you are building on 6.0 yet telling your app to run on 3.1?

Comment: I just posted the latest Dockerfile I tried. I used many different 6.0.x-x-arm32v7, neither of them worked so I tried 3.1